# Inserting data through gsa-template to atg sql with resume on error

Tags: atg

I am currently trying to insert a large amount of data into my repository through an xml (calling inputFiles within TemplateParser). However when a single record throws an error, like a key constraint, no more records will be processed. I understand it would be good to clean the data so that bad rows are not getting inserted, but because I cannot consistently control our subset of data in the test environments I can't guarantee that the tables referenced by the foreign constraints will have consistent data.

If I wrap the entire contents in a transaction then no records get inserted, if I wrap it with import-items it fails because of null constraints on the table (import-items tries to insert partial records). Wrapping each element in it's own transaction doesn't trap the error and it inserts each row up to the bad row but nothing after.

Is there another way that to allow for a resume on error scenario while importing data into the repository? Or a way to check constraints within the gsa-template before inserting?

The file for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE gsa-template SYSTEM "dynamosystemresource:/atg/dtds/gsa/gsa_1.0.dtd">
<gsa-template>
<transaction>
<add-item item-descriptor="vendorSku">
    <set-property name="skuItem"><![CDATA[0065-OC-OS]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="vendorSkuId"><![CDATA[853-6520]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="vendorItem"><![CDATA[781]]></set-property>
</add-item>
<add-item item-descriptor="vendorSku">
    <set-property name="skuItem"><![CDATA[0189-CRGONET-ONSI]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="vendorSkuId"><![CDATA[8007146]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="vendorItem"><![CDATA[76]]></set-property>
</add-item>
etc..
</gsa-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to find so far it is not possible to do exactly this without overloading internal ATG methods. However I did find that inserting data into the repository becomes much more resilient to bad data, duplicates etc... if you explicitly set the item-descriptor during the update rather then allow the repository to do it.

So in the above example if the id field of vendorSku was skuItem the insert statement can be modified to:

```
<add-item item-descriptor="vendorSku" id="0189-CRGONET-ONSI">
    <set-property name="vendorSkuId"><![CDATA[8007146]]></set-property>
    <set-property name="vendorItem"><![CDATA[76]]></set-property>
</add-item>
```

This way if the file is added multiple times it would update existing records rather then throwing errors because of the duplication. You can also use the `<update-item>` tag with the add flag set to true for the same behavior.